# How to generate amchart.js in new window

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I am trying to generate an amchart (https://www.amcharts.com/demos/bullet-chart/) bullet chart in a new window. When I run the code inline from a HTML doc it runs fine but when I try to generate the chart in a new window (see below) after the user hits submit, nothing happens i.e. no warnings or errors in the console. Here is my code:

```
 var OpenWindow4 = window.open("", "newin4", "width=1000,height=600,toolbar=no,scrollbars=" + scroll + ",menubar=no");
        OpenWindow4.document.write('<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/><title>Features</title><script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script><script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script><script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/none.js"></script><div class="chart-block"><div id="chartdiv1" style="width:100%; height:220px;"></div></div><script type="text/javascript"> (function () { var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv1", { "type": "serial", "theme": "none", "autoMargins": false, "marginTop": 30, "marginLeft": 80, "marginBottom": 30, "marginRight": 50, "dataProvider": [{ "category": "Evaluation", "excelent": 20, "good": 20, "average": 20, "poor": 20, "bad": 20, "limit": 78, "full": 100, "bullet": 65 }], "valueAxes": [{ "maximum": 100, "stackType": "regular", "gridAlpha": 0 }], "startDuration": 1, "graphs": [{ "fillAlphas": 0.8, "lineColor": "#19d228", "showBalloon": false, "type": "column", "valueField": "excelent" }, { "fillAlphas": 0.8, "lineColor": "#b4dd1e", "showBalloon": false, "type": "column", "valueField": "good" }, { "fillAlphas": 0.8, "lineColor": "#f4fb16", "showBalloon": false, "type": "column", "valueField": "average" }, { "fillAlphas": 0.8, "lineColor": "#f6d32b", "showBalloon": false, "type": "column", "valueField": "poor" }, { "fillAlphas": 0.8, "lineColor": "#fb7116", "showBalloon": false, "type": "column", "valueField": "bad" }, { "clustered": false, "columnWidth": 0.3, "fillAlphas": 1, "lineColor": "#000000", "stackable": false, "type": "column", "valueField": "bullet" },{ "columnWidth": 0.5, "lineColor": "#000000", "lineThickness": 3, "noStepRisers": true, "stackable": false, "type": "step", "valueField": "limit" }], "rotate": true, "columnWidth": 1, "categoryField": "category", "categoryAxis": { "gridAlpha": 0, "position": "left" } });})();</script> </head> </html>');
    }
```

Comment: furthermore, I can insert a canvas.js chart or d3.js chart and that works fine using the structure above - so it appears to be something weird with amChart.js charts when one uses `window.open` to generate the chart

Answer (score 0):

It seems that when you create a window like that DOM ready events are not being fired properly, so the chart does not even start to initialize.

To force the drawing of the chart add the following at the end of your chart code:

```
chart.write( "chartdiv1" );
```

That should do the trick.